# Extract names from a string using a list of names with grepl and a loop and add them to a new column in R

Tags: r, string, loops, grepl, edge-list

I have a dataset with a column containing names and a column indicating what the person did during the day. I am trying to figure out who met with whom in my dataset during that day using R. I created a vector containing the names in the dataset and used grepl in a loop to identify where the names appear in the column detailing the activity of the people in the dataset.

```
name <- c("Dupont","Dupuy","Smith") 

activity <- c("On that day, he had lunch with Dupuy in London.", 
              "She had lunch with Dupont and then went to Brighton to meet Smith.", 
              "Smith remembers that he was tired on that day.")

met_with <- c("Dupont","Dupuy","Smith")

df<-data.frame(name, activity, met_with=NA)


for (i in 1:length(met_with)) {
df$met_with<-ifelse(grepl(met_with[i], df$activity), met_with[i], df$met_with)
}
```

However, this solution is not satisfying for two reasons. I can't extract more than one name when the person met with more than one other person (ex Dupuy in my example) and I cannot tell R not to return the name of the person when the name is used instead of a pronoun in my activity column (ex. Smith).

Ideally, I would like the df to look like:

```
  name         activity                                            met_with                             
  Dupont       On that day, he had lunch with Dupuy in London.     Dupuy
  Dupuy        She had lunch with Dupont and then (...).           Dupont Smith
  Smith        Smith remembers that he was tired on that day.      NA
```

I am cleaning up the strings to construct an edge list and node list to conduct network analysis later on.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same logic as @Gki but using `stringr` functions and `mapply` instead of loop.

```
library(stringr)

pat <- str_c('\\b', df$name, '\\b', collapse = '|')
df$met_with <- mapply(function(x, y) str_c(setdiff(x, y), collapse = ' '), 
       str_extract_all(df$activity, pat), df$name)

df

#    name                                                           activity
#1 Dupont                    On that day, he had lunch with Dupuy in London.
#2  Dupuy She had lunch with Dupont and then went to Brighton to meet Smith.
#3  Smith                     Smith remembers that he was tired on that day.

#      met_with
#1        Dupuy
#2 Dupont Smith
#3
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, it works great. However, I'm having issues when I run it on the entire dataset as I think having a pattern with many many names makes R crash. I have been running the code on the full dataset that contains over 21000 rows of name + activity and I have a total of about 10 000 met_with names (there are duplicates in my "names" column since I have many common names like "Smith" in the dataset -- I will try to better identify which "Smith" the person met later on.).

Comment: If there are duplicate names in your data you can create the pattern with `pat <- str_c('\\b', unique(df$name), '\\b', collapse = '|')` to use only the unique names. Yes, but there is some limit on regular expression length so if you have many names this may not work without breaking it down.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It's been running for more than half an hour so I think breaking it down may be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdiff` to exclude the names to match for the row, and use `gregexpr` and `regmatches` to extract the matched names. Maybe also giving a `\\b` around the names might be considered.

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  df$met_with[i] <- paste(regmatches(df$activity[i],
   gregexpr(paste(setdiff(name, df$name[i]), collapse="|"),
   df$activity[i]))[[1]], collapse = " ")
}

df
#    name                                                           activity     met_with
#1 Dupont                    On that day, he had lunch with Dupuy in London.        Dupuy
#2  Dupuy She had lunch with Dupont and then went to Brighton to meet Smith. Dupont Smith
#3  Smith                     Smith remembers that he was tired on that day.
```

Another way using `Reduce` may be:

```
df$met_with <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
  i <- grepl(y, df$activity, fixed = TRUE) & y != df$name
  x[i] <- lapply(x[i], `c`, y)
  x
}, unique(name), vector("list", nrow(df)))

df
#    name                                                           activity      met_with
#1 Dupont                    On that day, he had lunch with Dupuy in London.         Dupuy
#2  Dupuy She had lunch with Dupont and then went to Brighton to meet Smith. Dupont, Smith
#3  Smith                     Smith remembers that he was tired on that day.          NULL
```